# Differential equation with random variable

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, stochastic-calculus

How can I derive analytically or compute numerically the solution to following differential equation

$$ dy/dt = y\cdot X\cdot (y\cdot X - g(y,X))\cdot X $$

where X is a random variable (e.g. from a normal distribution) and g is a known function of y and X, e.g. $g=E[(y\cdot X)^2]$ ?

Comment: Have a look at `ItoProcess` and similar. Maybe you could post a more specific example.

Comment: Well, this is a **specific** example arising e.g. from learning in neural networks. X is a random input to a node and y is the input weight to this node, which changes according to the above equation. I had a look at ItoProcesses, but I am not sure whether I have somehow to convert the above equation to an Ito process or if a different approach is needed.

Comment: Might be able to use `WhenEvent`, possibly in conjunction with `DiscreteVariables` (which might change values according to your random distribution).